# LESS - Potentially unhandled rejection [2] No matching definition was found?

Tags: css, less

I am trying to get this in the result from LESS:

```
.article-text {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

My attempt:

```
.box-shadow(@rgba: 0,0,0,0.25) {
    -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 100px rgba(@rgba);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(@rgba);
    box-shadow:         inset 0 0 100px rgba(@rgba);
}

.shadow,
.article-text {
    .box-shadow();
}
```

Error:

> Potentially unhandled rejection [2] No matching definition was found
>   for `.box-shadow()` in file /var/.../style.less line no. 613

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-mixins-with-multiple-parameters. In short, `.box-shadow` above is a mixin with 4 args. Use `.box-shadow(@rgba: 0,0,0,0.25;)` to make those comma separated values to be a part of the first arg.

Comment: And consider using Autoprefixer instead of bloating your code with vendor-prefixing mixin definitions/calls.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: But that would make it a *list* and require extract functions to work with `rgba` won't it?

Comment: @Harry, indeed I missed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note: As seven-phases-max mentions in his comment, it is always better to leave the prefixing stuff to either prefix-free or AutoPrefixer libraries.

In Less, the parameters defined for a parametric mixin are separated by either comma or semi-colon and so when you define a mixin as `.box-shadow(@rgba: 0,0,0,0.25)`, <strike>the compiler is confused. The value it encounters after the comma is not a variable but is a value.</strike> the compiler treats it as a mixin where there is one variable parameter (the `@rgba`) and three fixed value parameters (the 0,0,0.25).

The solution to your problem is to use them as separate parameters (r, g, b, a) instead of as a single parameter (rgba).

```css
.article-text (@r: 0, @g: 0, @b: 0, @a: 0.25) {
  -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 100px rgba(@r, @g, @b, @a);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(@r, @g, @b, @a);
  box-shadow:         inset 0 0 100px rgba(@r, @g, @b, @a);
}
#demo1{
  .article-text;
}
#demo2{
  .article-text(255,255,255,0.75);
}
```

---

Alternate ways to overcome this would have been to use a `;` (dummy) at the end like - `.article-text (@rgba: 0,0,0,0.25;)` or write it as - `.article-text (@rgba: ~"0,0,0,0.25")` but both have limitations. The first one would make the `@rgba` variable have a *list* as its default value but the `rgba` function (used within the mixin) expects only numbers as inputs. So, we would have to write ugly `extract` functions to get the individual values from the *list* and use it (like below example) whereas the second one would convert it into a single string and make it unusable.

```css
.article-text (@rgba : 0,0,0,0.25;) {
  @r: extract(@rgba, 1);
  @g: extract(@rgba, 2);
  @b: extract(@rgba, 3);
  @a: extract(@rgba, 4);
  -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 100px rgba(@r, @g, @b, @a);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px rgba(@r, @g, @b, @a);
  box-shadow:         inset 0 0 100px rgba(@r, @g, @b, @a);
}
#demo1{
  .article-text;
}
#demo1{
  .article-text(255,255,255,0.75;);
}
```

Comment: I'm quite new to LESS. but I am happy with this answer. Thank you! :-)